# ReactJS Get Children PropTypes

Tags: javascript, reactjs

is there any way to get the PropTypes of a Child Component (onClick) ?

i already archieved to log them with a function FROM the component,
but i would like to create a function which access the PropTypes of a Clicked Component

outside of the Component

```
Card.propTypes = { 
    glow: PropTypes.bool,
    entity: PropTypes.object,
    entityType: PropTypes.string
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will find two exampls below

1. with children : `props.children.props.glow` for example
2. traditional composition : `props.glow`

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Parent>
        <Child name="my second child" />
      </Parent>
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}

function Parent(props) {
  console.log(props);
  return (
    <div>
      <p>Parent</p>
      <Child name="my child" />
      <div>
        <p>name : {props.children.props.name}</p>
        {props.children}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

function Child(props) {
  return <p>{props.name}</p>;
}
```

Comment: hmm , that wont work with Child Components which have propTypes (just tryed it out anyway) :s